# Finding the expected number of cards drawn for picking x clubs?

Tags: probability

An easy (and probably dull) game is for player to draw card from a standard 52-card deck in turn.  Each will draw six cards at the starting round, and after that, each one will draw only one card from the remaining deck without replacement.  If all seven cards (including the newly drawn one) are from the same suit (club, heart, spade or diamond), the player wins.  Otherwise, he needs to drop one of his card (the card drawn and the card dropped can be same card) and it will be next player's turn.  This will be repeated until some player wins.

Half way of a two-player game, player A is having $7-x$ clubs and some other cards in his hand, thus he decides to go for club.  It is known that the remaining deck has $x_1$ clubs, $x_2$ non-clubs).  So what is the expected number of cards he need to draw until he wins? (Suppose that his opponent is unlucky enough that he will never win).  What if this is extended to a three- or four-player game?

For $x=1$ in a one-player's game, it is pretty simple that:
$$ E(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{x_2+1} \frac{\frac {{x_2}!}{({x_2}-n+1)!}}{\frac{({x_1}+{x_2})!}{({x_1}+{x_2}-n+1)!}} $$
For x=1 in a two player's game, it requires a bit calculation but still manageable (given that $x_1$ and $x_2$ are not big numbers).
so what about $x=2$ or higher in a n-player's game?

Comment: Why do we need a second player, if we assume this second player will never win? Which is the simplest description of this game? Why not start with one player, getting $7$ cards from the beginning? Why do we restrict to clubs, when the player may have none at the beginning? If only clubs count, it would be better to use cards in two colors only, $13$ times $\clubsuit$ and $39$ times some dummy color $\square$. Please give a clear question rather than a good story..

Comment: "Suppose that the opponent is unlucky enough that she will never win" can be interpreted in two very different ways. I would usually tend on understand it to mean that you're looking for the conditional expectation of the number of cards $A$ draws, conditioned on $A$ winning the game. But to calculate that, we'd need to know $B$'s strategy, and you didn't say anything at all about that. Thus it seems more likely that what you mean is that $B$ should just be completely ignored. But in that case, why would it matter how many players are in the game?

Comment: "Suppose that his opponent is unlucky enough that he will never win" is a statement to simplify the question.  As neither the opponent's current hand nor his/her strategy is known, it is impossible to get the result.  Hence it is simpler just assume the opponent is unlucky enough so that he will never win at first.  In this case, he's role is simple to draw and discard cards (with a proabability).  This is the very common situation in the real game.